# Mongodb - aggregate by embedded document id overwrite the outer document _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this kind of 'comment' model:

```
{ _id: <comment-id>,
  user: {
    id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    name: String
  },
  sharedToUsers:          [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  repliedToUsers:         [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
}
```

And I want to query for all comments which pass the following conditions:

1. sharedToUsers array is empty
2. repliedToUsers array is empty

But also, I want the result to contain only 1 comment (the latest comment) per user by the user id.

I've tried to create this aggregate (Node.js, mongoose):

```
     Comment.aggregate(
        { $match: { "sharedToUsers": [], "repliedToUsers": [] } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$user.id",
                user: { $first: "$user" },
            }
        },
        function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (!err) {
                res.send(result);
            } else {
                res.status(500).send({err: err});
            }
        });
```

It is actually working, but the serious problem is that the results comments _id field is been overwritten by the nested user _id.

How can I keep the aggregate working but not to overwrite the original comment _id field?

Thanks

Comment: Push the comment `_id` into the group results like you did with `user`, e.g. `comment_id : { "$first" : "$_id" }`.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have a solution.

All I wanted is to group by _id but to return the result documents with their _id field (which is been overwritten when using $group operator).

What I did is like wdberkley said, I've added comment_id : { "$first" : "$_id" } but then I wanted not to return the comment_id field (because it doesn't fit my model) so I've created a $project which put the comment_id in the regular _id field.

This is basically how it looks:

```
Comment.aggregate(
        {
            $match: {
                "sharedToUsers": [], "repliedToUsers": []
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                comment_id: { $last: "$_id" },
                _id: "$user.id",
                content: { $last: "$content" },
                urlId: { $last: "$urlId" },
                user: { $last: "$user" }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: "$comment_id",
                content: "$content",
                urlId: "$urlId",
                user: "$user"
            }
        },
        { $skip: parsedFromIndex },
        { $limit: (parsedNumOfComments - parsedFromIndex) },
        function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (!err) {
                Comment.populate(result, { path: "urlId"}, function(err, comments) {
                   if (!err) {
                       res.send(comments);
                   } else {
                       res.status(500).send({err: err});
                   }
                });
            } else {
                res.status(500).send({err: err});
            }
        });
```

thanks wdbkerkley!